# Concept: How are declarations linked to apropriate definitions

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

How exactly does a header file or any forward declarations know which definition it is referring to?

I understand that .cpp files are compiled independently, and we need a header file or forward declaration to access members of another .cpp file. But when we declare a member, we don't explicitly tell the compiler where to get the definition from.

Here is a case that I can think of: 
Say I have two cpp files 'one.cpp' and 'two.cpp'.
Both 'one.cpp' and 'two.cpp' have a member 'int func(int x)' that have different implementations (but have the exact name and format). 
If we have a header file or declaration of this function somewhere outside these two files, how does the compiler know which definition to take?

Comment: This is done by the linker.

Comment: If you had tried to build your example, you wouldn't be asking this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `If we have a header file or declaration of this function somewhere outside these two files, how does the compiler know which definition to take?`

It's the [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) which takes one or more object files or libraries as input and combines them to produce an executable file. In doing so, it resolves references to external symbols i.e. it looks for definition of all external functions and global variables both from other '.obj' files and external libraries, assigns final addresses to procedures/functions and variables, and revises code and data to reflect new addresses.

Let's consider the example you are mentioning in question:

> `Say I have two cpp files 'one.cpp' and 'two.cpp'. Both 'one.cpp' and 'two.cpp' have a member 'int func(int x)' that have different implementations....`

Say, `one.cpp`:

```
int func(int x)
{
        return x+1;
}
```

and `two.cpp`:

```
int func(int x)
{
        return x+2;
}
```

and a header file declaring `func()` function, say `myinc.h`:

```
int func(int x);
```

and `main()` which is calling `func()`, say `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <myinc.h>

int main()
{
        int res;
        res = func(10);
        std::cout << res << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

I can create the object file of `main.cpp` because an object file can refer to symbols that are not defined.

`>g++ -I . -c main.cpp`

Now let's examine the object file `main.o` using `nm` command, the output is:

```
Symbols from main.o:

Name                  Value           Class        Type         Size             Line  Section

_GLOBAL__I_main     |0000000000000078|   t  |              FUNC|0000000000000015|     |.text    
_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii|0000000000000038|   t  |              FUNC|0000000000000040|     |.text    
_Z4funci            |                |   U  |            NOTYPE|                |     |*UND*
.......
.......<SNIP>
```

The `func()` function **Class** is **U**, which means Undefined.
The compiler doesn't mind if it could not find the definition of a particular function, it would just assume that the function was defined in another file.

The linker, on the other hand, may look at multiple files and try to find references to the functions that weren't mentioned.

So, when we try creating an executable from the object files `one.o`, `two.o` and `main.o`:

```
>g++ two.o one.o main.o -o outexe
one.o: In function `func(int)':
one.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `func(int)'
two.o:two.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here you can see the linker is throwing `multiple definition` error for `func()` because it find two definitions of `func()`.

There is a [one definition rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) in c++, which states that:

> In the entire program, an object or non-inline function cannot have more than one definition; if an object or function is used, it must have exactly one definition. You can declare an object or function that is never used, in which case you don't have to provide a definition. In no event can there be more than one definition.

So, the program is violating the ODR because it contains two definitions of the same function declaration.

If we do not provide either `one.o` or `two.o` object file to linker, means, if we just provide one definition of `func()` it will generate exe:

```
>g++ one.o main.o -o outexe
```

and if we examine `outexe`, we get:

```
Symbols from outexe:

Name                  Value           Class        Type         Size             Line  Section

.....<SNIP>    
_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii|000000000040082c|   t  |              FUNC|0000000000000040|     |.text
_Z4funci            |00000000004007e4|   T  |              FUNC|000000000000000f|     |.text
.......
.......<SNIP>
```

The symbol `func()` is of **Type** - **FUNC** and **Class** - **T**, which means - `The symbol is in the text (code) section`.

Answer (score 3):

Resolving a definition for each declaration is performed by the linker. Each declaration must have a unique definition. While a function may be declared multiple times, each function must be defined exactly once in all compilation units which are to be linked. If there is more than one definition for a function with the same signature, then the linker will throw an error and refuse to finish building the executable.

I suggest that you create the example files that you described and try to build them into a single executable. You will see the error that I describe here.